# Sbt cross release: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ivy file not found in cache for

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-release

I'm trying to cross publish a library for scala 2.12/2.11 using `sbt-release`, and getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ivy file not found in cache` exception in the 2.11 part (things continue for 2.12 and go all the way to being uploaded to sonatype)

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last monadic-rxJS/*:deliver for the full output.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ivy file not found in cache for in.nvilla#monadic-rx-cats_sjs0.6_2.11;0.2.0!
```

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/742a87a8b806ac73a5a804ed4b15b700) the complete sbt output, and this is the current state of the [`build.sbt`](https://github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/monadic-html/blob/690eb5506d2b3bf41f27f66c4721709796a9a6dc/build.sbt).

Comment: I should maybe add that I've tried the obvious `git clean -fdx && rm -rf ~/.ivy2`...

Comment: wish I could help :D

Comment: long shot: sbt update?

Comment: Has this been solved? I'm hitting the same issue now.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen My solution ended up being rewriting [`sbt-release`  in bash](https://github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/monadic-html/blob/ff8b02103e7e02bc89aec1b1b049b8bd59424498/release.sh).

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain: ok, we now use 'sbt clean release'.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen Can you tell us how you make it work? Just `sbt clean release` does not do the trick for me.

Comment: Finally it worked also for me. Similar code as the one posted by @OlivierBlanvillain but without `in This Build` using sbt 1.0.4

Comment: @jonas-anso we use it with sbt clean release. And we removed the clean from the set of release commands.